# nested dicts update

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this snippet

```
dict_a = {'key_1_lv_1': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
      'key_2_lv_1': {'key_1_lv_2': 'value_1', 'key_2_lv_2': 'value_2', 'key_3_lv_2': 'value_3'},
      }

dict_b = {'key_1_lv_1': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
      'key_2_lv_1': {'key_1_lv_2': 'new_value'},
      }
```

When i execute this row:

```
dict_a.update(dict_b)
```

and print dict_a['key_2_lv_1'], it gives me:

```
{'key_1_lv_2': 'new_value'}, only. The other 2 key-value pairs are missing,, but i need them.
```

If the dicts are not nested I get the other 2 key-value pairs.
So is there any slick solution to get the missing key-values in the nested dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively update:

```py
def recursive_update(d1, d2):
    for key in d2:
        # Check if the key exists on both dicts and merge them if they do
        if key in d1 and isinstance(d1[key], dict) and isinstance(d2[key], dict):
            # Recursively call the same function
            recursive_update(d1[key], d2[key])
        # You can add other conditions for merging lists or other data types here too if you want
        else:
            d1[key] = d2[key]
    # Note this function works in place, so there is no return
```

Usage:

```
recursive_update(dict_a, dict_b)
```

If you know for sure that your data structure will be a dict of dicts with exactly 1 level of nesting, @leaf_yakitori's answer will work too and is much more concise. This function works if some of the values are not dicts or if there is more than 2 levels of nesting.

Comment: What you are talking about is possible, that's why took your solution. It is more accurate in my case, i think.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
dict_a = {'key_1_lv_1': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
      'key_2_lv_1': {'key_1_lv_2': 'value_1', 'key_2_lv_2': 'value_2', 'key_3_lv_2': 'value_3'},
      }
dict_b = {'key_1_lv_1': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
      'key_2_lv_1': {'key_1_lv_2': 'new_value'},
      }
for k,v in dict_b.items():
    dict_a[k] = {**dict_a.get(k,{}),**v}
print(dict_a)
```

result:

```
{'key_1_lv_1': {'key_1': 'value_1'}, 'key_2_lv_1': {'key_1_lv_2': 'new_value', 'key_2_lv_2': 'value_2', 'key_3_lv_2': 'value_3'}}
```